# Scrapy Installation on pyCharm

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to install Scrapy via the project interpreter but I end with the error. Later I tried installing using pip install Scrapy but I end up with the same error. The error details are:

```
running build_ext
generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-2.7\\Release\\_padding.c'
    already up-to-date
    generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-2.7\\Release\\_constant_time.c'
    already up-to-date
    generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-2.7\\Release\\_openssl.c'
    already up-to-date
    building '_openssl' extension
    C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include "-IC:\aaaa\PC" /Tcbuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_openssl.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_openssl.obj
    _openssl.c
    build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_openssl.c(434) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: Can you try installing the [binary version of cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-windows)? It should be a matter of running `pip install --only-binary cryptography cryptography`

Comment: Thanks for you help

Answer (score -1):

You could be missing Microsoft C++ for Python 2, since the file that cannot be opened is from it.

The download is here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Comment: Thanks for your help.